# Is that possible set defual role required for all resourcce in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

Is it possible set default `ROLE_ADMIN` for all resource then overwrite it on the specified resource with `ROLE_USER` or `IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY`?

Currently I use `@Secured({"ROLE_ADMIN"})` for admin users (e.g. get list all user), `@Secured({"ROLE_USER", "ROLE_ADMIN"})` for normal users (e.g. get list their orders) and `@Secured("IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY")` for anonymously users (e.g. get list products or sign-in).

Now I need set `ROLE_ADMIN` as default required role for all resource and then override it on by resource requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "test", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ROLE_ADMIN')")
public class TestResource {

@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ROLE_USER')")
@RequestMapping(value = "somePath", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public Object apiEndpoint() {return null;}

}
```

Put a default `@PreAuthorize` on the top of the controller. It will apply to all public methods. If you want to override: put another `@PreAuthorize` above the method.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `@PreAuthorize()`.

From docs:

[Docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/access/prepost/PrePostAnnotationSecurityMetadataSource.html)

> Annotations may be specified on classes or methods, and
>   method-specific annotations will take precedence.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/api", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ROLE_ADMIN')")
public class SomeResource {
    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ROLE_USER')")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/getme", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,method=  RequestMethod.GET)
    public Object getMe() {return null;}
}
```

you should add

`@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity` if you are using java config on your security class.

```
 <security:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" /> if you are using xml config.
```